# Looking for an Isekai manga where the mc is in an orphanage

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This is an Isekai Japanese manga which I read about a year ago, and only first few chapters at that so, it seemed pretty new and was fan translated. It was about a boy (at that time I guess he was 5-8 years old) in an orphanage run by a very renowned mage.

As much as I remember it, I probably read it on some other-than-my-usual sites and it was medieval where there was nobility.

It was not like he adopted him (like in Kenja no Mago) or just met him recently (like in the 8th son). That orphanage had other children too and when he noticed his potential in magic he made him his disciple. The magic displayed was nothing sort of elemental or summoning or ritual. It was the classical way magic is displayed like in Kenja no Mago (although I only read the first few chapters).

Comment: Did you read this in paper form? Electronically? What websites do you tend to patronize? Was this an official translation? Fan translation? Was the orphanage in a medieval world? Modern? What sort of magic showed up in the universe? Was it rituals? Calling up demons? Elemental affinities? Mind magic? [This list of question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help prompt you for details to [edit] in.

Comment: Are you sure he was in an orphanage and not just an orphan? The provided answer would fit a lot of what you are asking but not the part about being in an orphanage.

Comment: Yes i am sure about he was in the orphanage, taught magic by someone who was held with high regard even among the nobles and royals(i guess so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be *[Rettougan no Tensei Majutsushi: Shitagerareta Saikyou no Minashigo ga Isekai de Musou Suru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rettougan-no-tensei-majutsushi-shitagerareta-saikyou-no-minashigo-ga-isekai-de-musou-suru)*, alternately spelled as *Rettou Gan No Tensei Majutsushi ~ Shiitage Rareta Saikyou No Minashigo Ga Isekai De Musou Suru*.

> Abel, a boy abandoned by his family because of the fear his unparalleled talent for magic evoked on them, was taken to an orphanage and taught magic by a former great magician. Eventually, his ability far surpassed that of his teacher and after receiving an invitation from the magical society known as Chaos Raid, he embarks on a journey with the fire hero, Maria and the water hero Daytona and later, the ash hero, Cain. This is the story of Abel's childhood and adolescence before his reincarnation.

A young boy is kicked out onto the streets by his aunt after his mother's death, due to displaying magical powers. He is then taken in by a man who runs an orphanage, who also instructs him in the use of magic. By the time the story begins in earnest, the boy has been living at the orphanage for over two years. This is a relatively new manga, with just sixteen chapters.

This doesn't seem to be an isekai, since there's no indication that the boy ever lived in another world. However, there is [a related series](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rettougan-no-tensei-majutsushi-shiitage-rareta-moto-yuusha-wa-mirai-no-sekai-wo-yoyuu-de-ikinuku) where the boy reincarnates himself 200 years into the future.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly it!!! I had so less info to give. ty again .

Answer (score 0):

This might be *[Kenja no Mago](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36407/Kenja_no_Mago)*

[image: Front cover of the first volume of Kenja no Mago]

> In the kingdom of Earlshide, Merlin Walford was once regarded as a national hero, hailed for both his power and achievements. Preferring a quiet life however, he secludes himself deep in the rural woods, dedicating his time to raising an orphan that he saved. This orphan is Shin, a normal salaryman in modern-day Japan who was reincarnated into Merlin's world while still retaining his past memories. As the years pass, Shin displays unparalleled talent in both magic casting and martial arts, much to Merlin's constant amazement.
>
> On his 15th birthday however, it becomes apparent that Shin only developed his combat skills and nothing else, leaving him with blatant social awkwardness, a lack of common sense, and a middling sense of responsibility. As a result, Shin enrolls in the kingdom's Magic Academy to hone his skills and mature among other teenagers. However, living a normal life is impossible, as he is established as a local celebrity almost as soon as he arrives.
>
> Kenja no Mago follows Shin Walford's high school life in the capital as he makes new friends, learns about the world, and fights off the various forces of evil surrounding him and his city.

Found with a search for `isekai orphanage run by wizard -"isekai de kojiin"`

Comment: I don't think it was a popular manga cause i didn't read it on my usual go-to sites.

Comment: So you think this one is too mainstream to be the right one? Amy other details that don't match to help us narrow this down?

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear. Actually i have already read this manga and seen its anime and since anime are for those which are popular ones since, its a business venture. The one in question is the one that I am sure is not this much popular as kenja no mago as neither it had an anime(which i am sure, if it had i qould be aware of)  and nor did i read it on a website that i frequently visit except for one case of being mangadex. But its servers are down for weeks.